# How to pass "yes/no" to prompt from python code?

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

I have tiny little python code which logs in to a remote machine and gets the output of a command and prints to a file..
Here for a particular command, the server asks for Y or N, how do i pass an Yes to it and get the desired output?

## Here is the sample output from the server:

root@nnodee11cc40c:/home/usr/redsuren# controlport rst 0:3:3

WARNING: Port 0:3:3 may have active Smart SAN target driven zones that may be disrupted. If changing the port configuration, remove the Smart SAN zoning by using the removehost command. This must be done before changing the port configuration; otherwise, you will not be able to manage the zone on the switch associated with this port.

Are you sure you want to run controlport rst on port 0:3:3?
select q=quit y=yes n=no:  ---------> Here i have to tell the program to enter y

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to automate pressing 'y' & 'enter' with Python. You can easily do this by PyAutoGui.

First, execute `pip install pyautogui` in the command prompt. 
Then import it to your code by using `import pyautogui` 
Now for achieving this you have to put the following code where you want to press 'y' & 'enter':

```py
pyautogui.press('y')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

But this may not be timed according to when it asks so you may need to time it yourself
by adding `time.sleep(<numberOfSeconds>)` after importing it by `import time`

Now here is the full answer:

```py
import pyautogui, time

# Your code here

time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.press('y')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

But if my answer is not what you asked for, then you have to give us your code so we can understand your question better thus answer it to your needs.